# Как сделать всплывающее окно при закрытии вкладки?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать, чтобы при закрытии сайта вскакивало окно?
Причём чтобы оно вскакивало не тогда, когда курсор покидает область
отображения сайта, а когда пользователь нажимает на закрытие вкладки.
Также интересует вопрос, как сделать автоматическое закрытие этого
окна через определенное время.

Comment: окно браузер не даст сделать всплывающим на закрытие. можно confirm сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть только один способ показать уведомление на закрытие окна/таба, событие [beforeunload](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror#window-onbeforeunload).